# use of case when else in sql , not getting intended result

Tags: sql, join, sql-server-2008-r2

I have following DB table:

[image]

In this Questionmaster table, there is Language=1 for English and Language=2 for spanish question.

I wanted to display it as:

```
SrNo       EnglishQuestion        Spanish Question


1            English Question     Spanish Question

2            Where do you live?   Kuthe rahatos?
```

For this i used following query:

> select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY QMID) AS SrNo,  CASE Language WHEN
>   1 THEN Question end,CASE Language WHEN 2 THEN Question end   from
>   QuestionMaster

but i failed to get the result.

Please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need an aggregation to do what you want.  One row can only have one language on it.

Try this:

```
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY QMID) AS SrNo,
       max(CASE Language WHEN 1 THEN Question end) as English,
       max(CASE Language WHEN 2 THEN Question end) as Spanish
from QuestionMaster
group by QMID
```